# upgraded to IIS 7 and now large uploads are failing

Tags: file-upload, iis-7

I recently moved my classic ASP application from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5 and then received a lot of complaints when users tried to upload a lot of files or a large file.

After doing some research, I changed the maxRequestEntityAllowed, using the following command,

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/asp/limits.maxRequestEntityAllowed:"2147483647" /commit:apphost
```

That immediately solved the issue. The problem is, it stops working at some point and the errors come back. It's as though the settings gets overwritten in the metabase but when I check the limits section in the ASP > Limits section, the new value is stil recorded.

If I re-enter the large valure again, the uploads work again. How is this being overwritten?

I have made sure that the this new value is set in the web.config file and the app.config file too. I have restarted IIS several time and event used the above appcmd when IIS was in a shutdown state.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with a 404.15 error - querystring too long and a whole lot of coincidence thrown in for good measure.